# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'Decimal'

Tags: python, django, tags, null

I have a django app that manages VAT. For instance, it can calculate the VAT for all sales from the European Union.

```
vat = purchases[0].vat.vat
eu_sales = Sale.objects.filter(country_type='2')
eu_amount = (eu_sales.aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))['price'])  * vat/100
```

However, today I copyied my files to another machine. Then I received an error

`unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'Decimal'`

I realised that I was getting this error because there is no `eu_amount` value stored yet. In overwords, there is no vale for `eu_amount` so it cannot multiply to a decimal value. Here is what I have in my template

```
{{eu_amount}}
```

Is there way to filter this template tag? I want to say something like if value the value is None, (or Null) then its 0.

Comment: Can't you make a Python filtering, by looking at Boolean value of `eu_amount is None`? Moreover (but I'm not working with Django so I might be wrong) are you sure it's not `eu_sales` that is concerned? As `eu_amount` is not an operand of `*`.

Comment: `(eu_sales.aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))['price'])` would be neater as `eu_sales.aggregate(price=Sum('amount'))['price']` (no spaces around the `=` when it's a keyword is standard Python style and the parentheses serve no purpose).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use a default value like this.

```
eu_amount = (eu_sales.aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))['price']) or 0  * vat/100
```

But the cleanest way is probably to test if your Sum returns nothing, then to display some kind of warning message, because this should'nt happen.

Comment: `@Thibault J` Yeah, I see you problem. If I have your definition of eu_amount and if there is a value of eu_ammount, for some reason it does not multiply with `vat/100`

Comment: `@Thibault J:` Update I think it needs or 0 part in a bracket `eu_amount = ((eu_sales.aggregate(price = Sum('amount'))['price']) or 0) * vat/100`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line
`vat = purchases[0].vat.vat` 
to 
`vat = purchases[0].vat.vat or 0`

Comment: The order of NoneType, Decimal implies it is the first argument of the multiplication that is None, not the second.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't think too long before answering and the question seemed to suggest the vat variable could be None... Sorry!

Comment: `@piokuc` its the decimal variable eu_amount that is the problem, not vat.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
{% if item %}
    something
{% else %}
    something different
{% endif %}
```

Taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

I'm nearly sure, I've seen this .vat.vat somewhere lately ;)